# SyntaxError: invalid syntax - yield from iterable when using celery

Tags: python, syntax-error, celery, python-import

I have a basic flask app that I am creating to send emails periodically. And when I installed celery, I am getting a syntax error in one of the libraries called `more_itertools` it depends on.

```
...
[838946]      yield from iterable
[838950]               ^
[838955]  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am unable to troubleshoot further. Please help.

- Celery version - 4.3.0
- Python version - 3.6.8

**Requirements.txt:**

```
alembic==1.3.1
amqp==2.5.2
billiard==3.6.1.0
blinker==1.4
celery==4.3.0
certifi==2019.6.16
chardet==3.0.4
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.1
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Mail==0.9.1
Flask-Migrate==2.5.2
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.1
idna==2.8
importlib-metadata==1.3.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.1
kombu==4.6.7
Mako==1.1.0
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
more-itertools==8.0.2
pymaging==0.1
pymaging-png==0.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
python-editor==1.0.4
pytz==2019.3
qrcode==6.1
razorpay==1.2.0
requests==2.22.0
six==1.12.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.11
urllib3==1.25.3
vine==1.3.0
Werkzeug==0.15.5
zipp==0.6.0
```

**__init__.py**

```py
...
celery = Celery(app.name, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
celery.conf.update(app.config)
...
```

**views/home.py**

```py
...
r = send_mail(email).delay(10, 20)
...
@celery.task
def send_mail(email):
    # email stuff
```

**Complete traceback:**

```
[838493]  mod_wsgi (pid=12557): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/myapp.wsgi'.
[838556]  Traceback (most recent call last):
[838580]    File "/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/myapp.wsgi", line 4, in <module>
[838617]      from myapp import app as application
[838626]    File "/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/myapp/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
[838642]      from celery import Celery
[838650]    File "/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 509, in __getattr__
[838665]      module = __import__(self._object_origins[name], None, None, [name])
[838672]    File "/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
[838686]      from celery import _state
[838693]    File "/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/_state.py", line 17, in <module>
[838705]      from celery.utils.threads import LocalStack
[838712]    File "/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
[838726]      from .functional import memoize  # noqa
[838745]    File "/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/utils/functional.py", line 10, in <module>
[838759]      from kombu.utils.functional import (LRUCache, dictfilter, is_list, lazy,
[838766]    File "/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
[838779]      from .compat import fileno, maybe_fileno, nested, register_after_fork
[838786]    File "/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/compat.py", line 14, in <module>
[838798]      import importlib_metadata
[838805]    File "/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/importlib_metadata/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
[838818]      import zipp
[838825]    File "/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zipp.py", line 12, in <module>
[838844]      import more_itertools
[838868]    File "/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/more_itertools/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
[838893]      from .more import *  # noqa
[838939]    File "/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/more_itertools/more.py", line 460
[838946]      yield from iterable
[838950]               ^
[838955]  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**Apache configuration:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@myapp.com
    ServerName myapp.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=myuser group=sudo threads=5 python-path=/var/www/myapp.com:/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/myapp.com/public_html/myapp.wsgi

    DocumentRoot /var/www/myapp.com/public_html
    <Directory /var/www/myapp.com/public_html>
        WSGIProcessGroup myapp
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
        WSGIScriptReloading On
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**myapp.wsgi**

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/")

from myapp import app as application

from werkzeug.debug import DebuggedApplication
application = DebuggedApplication(application, True)
```

Comment: how do you the celery worker? or is it from flask app error? where from is the stacktrace

Comment: I don't understand your first question. The stack trace is from the apache error log (WSGI).

Comment: Please add your apache configuration for the server block where the error happens

Comment: @AlexandrShurigin, I have edited my question to add the conf. Please check.

Comment: I recently upgraded from centos 7.6 to 7.7 and started getting this error where things works before. It might be an issue with the package in pip though. Looks like it's getting the wrong version. For me it makes no sense for it to be user space, pip should "just work". It may have been downloading the python3 version for python2 because installing with pip3 instead of pip fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Try to add

> **python-home=directory**
>
> Set the location of the Python virtual environment to be used by the daemon processes. The directory to use is that which sys.prefix is set to for the Python virtual environment. The virtual environment can have been created by virtualenv, pyvenv or python -m venv.
>
> Note that the Python virtual environment must have been created using the same base Python version as was used to compile the mod_wsgi module. You can’t use this to force mod_wsgi to somehow use a different Python version than it was compiled for. If you want to use a different version of Python, you will need to reinstall mod_wsgi, compiling it for the version you want. It is not possible for the one mod_wsgi instance to run applications for both Python 2 and 3 at the same time.

From modwsgi docs https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html#wsgidaemonprocess

### 2. Print the current "apache running python version"

Add `print(sys.version)` to your `myapp.wsgi` script to see in the apache logs python running version

Comment: After setting python-home to my venv, the error log is flooded with `ImportError: No module named site`.

Comment: can you post current config please? with the changes

Comment: here is the current config - https://gist.github.com/claudiamaximus/4883dc1f01b247c130bc42c3733d95bc#file-myapp-com-conf .

Comment: Have you done step #2 from my answer?

> print(sys.version) to your myapp.wsgi

Comment: I did. But I don't see anything other than [this](https://gist.github.com/claudiamaximus/3c0eb5a06794eb556285be47ed01c67a) in the error log. `[194050]mod_wsgi (pid=26641): Target WSGI script '/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/myapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.` But I am getting the same even when I recompile mod_wsgi to confirm it's compiled for Python 3.6.

Comment: I appreciate the help and time taken Alexandr. I have posted the issue on `more-itertools` repo as well. Looks like another user is experiencing a similar issue. https://github.com/erikrose/more-itertools/issues/355

Comment: I am sorry to say, but it seems like it is impossible (or very hard) to debug without having shell access & etc. Without checkin the whole configuration & playing on it "in live" I am out of any other ideas for the moment :(

Comment: I did find the problem. It's like deets said, the mod_wsgi is running python 2.7. The whole WSGI config is so confusing. I am working on it. Thank you for helping me so far.

Comment: So that helped `Add print(sys.version) to your myapp.wsgi`? :)

Comment: The test script did, yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you are really running Python3.6. The python interpreter is actually chosen by mod_wsgi, and is probably an older one that does not support the `yield from`-Syntax yet.

See https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-installation-in-use for instructions on how to verify your actual chosen interpreter.

Comment: I am positive I am running python 3.6. `WSGIDaemonProcess myapp user=myuser group=sudo threads=5 python-path=/var/www/myapp.com:/var/www/myapp.com/public_html/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
`

Comment: That only proves that the used python interpreter will attempt to import modules from the python3.6 site packages. It has nothing to do with the version of the actual interpreter. It's really very simple: `yield from` is syntax introduced version 3.3. There is no way it's not recognized in anything later. Have you tried the procedure suggested in my link?

Comment: I'll follow the link you provided. Could you please tell me where I should implement it? In `myapp.wsgi`?

Comment: Printing out `sys.version` in the python interpreter I got `3.6.8 (default, Jan 14 2019, 11:02:34)
[GCC 8.0.1 20180414 (experimental) [trunk revision 259383]]
`

Comment: Also the above version was printed from inside the `venv`. Deactivating it, and repeating it out of `venv`, this is the output - `3.6.9 (default, Nov  7 2019, 10:44:02)
[GCC 8.3.0]
`

Comment: Many systems have both versions of python and get things wrong / separate the version differently which means it might not be your fault. I wouldn't trust some sub script not to do something like mess with the path / how the binary is found or not use the user path or something. If you did anything to bootstrap which python version to use as default for your user it likely wont always carry down to scripts that reinvoke python. I had the same thing with itertools and in my case I'm sure they messed something up not me.

Comment: @jgmjgm while this is true in general, these musings do not apply for mod_wsgi which is linked to a concrete libpython.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, I am working on python2.7 environment.
The root cause is because celery has dependency to kombu,

try use `pip freeze | grep kombu` to check your kombu version

I saw my version is 4.6.0, 
I removed 4.6.0 and downgraded to 4.1.0

Solved this problem